# Amazon s3 storage video takes long time to load

Tags: video, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Good day. Please i have a website i want to develope. Its a video viewing website where i will be sharing a local drama for my viewers. Each darama is of the average of 1:10:00 duration . My problem is , i tried hosting the videos on amazon, but now a video takes very long time to start streaming. around 20 min sometimes. I am confused and is not sutre what the problem is? Also i am using joomla for the video, the template i am using accept only .mp4 videos and its kind of difficult for me. I am not sure if there is a better cms for the site?. Would appreciate any recommendation.

Also hosting the video, is amazon s3 a better choice or is there any other means? i am currently checking on vimeo pro , but is not sure if that would do the trick?

my site http://hantsitv.com/

Answer (score 1):

S3 is great for just storing the video, but you want to use Amazon [Cloudfront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) for streaming it since it is optimized for content delivery.

Comment: Thank you sir. But is that amazon Cludfront necessary ? I ask because i see the videos are streaming without that. Or what are the benefit of using it ?

Comment: @NuruSalihu Cloudfront caches videos on servers close to your users.